# How can I call a generic method from a reflected context?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a `Constraints` object which will get a set of rules that other objects have to adhere to.

`constraints` has a method called `GetEnumValueRange<T>()` where `T` is a type of Enum.

So for example, I could have an enum defined as:

```
[Flags]
public enum BoxWithAHook
{
    None = 0,
    Thing1 = 1,
    Thing2 = 2,
    ...
    // lots of other things that might be in the box
    ThingN = N
}
```

I could then get a range of values which are valid within a given context for `BoxWithAHook`:

```
var val = constraints.GetEnumValueRange<BoxWithAHook>();
```

The problem is that I'm trying to use reflection to do this work. I can't specify that the type is `BoxWithAHook` because it could be anything that extends `Enum`. This is an example of what I have:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
{
    var val = constraints.GetEnumValueRange<>(); // what is the generic type here?

    // now I can use val to get the constraint values
}
```

Is it possible for me to specify the generic type? ideally, this would work:

```
constraints.GetEnumValueRange<propertyInfo.PropertyType>();
```

but it obviously doesn't

Comment: Andrei is right in terms of if you **must** call a generic method, but note that this type of reflection can hurt performance if you are doing *lots* of it. If you are, there are ways of optimizing this. Not worth it just for a single call, though. Lukazoid is right in that if you **are** using reflection, then having a generics-based API is going to be a pain. In fact, I re-wrote the entire core of a large library to change generic `Foo<T>(...)` methods into `Foo(Type type, ...)` methods. Much happier with the result now.

Answer (score 2):

You might need a little bit of reflection via `MethodInfo` here:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Constraints).GetMethod("GetEnumValueRange");
    MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
    var val = genericMethod.Invoke(constraints, null);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make an overload of `GetEnumValueRange` which takes a `Type` parameter, so you end up with something like this:

```
public class Constraints
{
    public IEnumerable GetEnumValueRange(Type enumType)
    {
        // Logic here
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumValueRange<T>()
    {
        return GetEnumValueRange(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use `constraints.GetEnumValueRange(propertyInfo.PropertyType)`, I'd personally avoid reflection if there was a usable alternative like this.